# Matlab opengl software rendering after upgrading to ubuntu 20.4 - low-level graphic issue

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, rendering

After I upgraded my OS to ubuntu 20.04 I'm experiencing problems with matlab rendering. When I open the program I get this message:

```
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
Gtk-Message: 14:38:28.776: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

The program runs normally but crashes (when I say crash I mean everything just closes without giving me an error message) when plotting.

I read a lot about this issue and tried to follow other users suggestions but without success:

I tried to open matlab from the terminal with the flag:

```
 matlab -nosoftwareopengl
```

which gives me the following errors in the terminal

```
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

and in Matlab:

```
MATLAB has experienced a low-level graphics error, and may not have drawn correctly.
Read about what you can do to prevent this issue at Resolving Low-Level Graphics Issues then restart MATLAB.
To share details of this issue with MathWorks technical support,
please include this file with your service request.
Couldn't create JOGL canvas--using painters
Couldn't create JOGL canvas--using painters
Couldn't create JOGL canvas--using painters
Couldn't create JOGL canvas--using painters
```

The suggestions for resolving low-level graphic issues include setting opengl to 'software' which leads me back to the initial problem.

Another suggestion was to upgrade my Graphics Hardware Drivers, but since I've just upgraded my Ubuntu, shouldn't they have been upgraded in the process?

I can't believe how much time I've already spent on this, so any help is highly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Comment: Have you try to manually `apt-get install/upgrade` the missing module (canberra-gtk) ? Check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed)

Comment: what is your MATLAB version?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to install and upgrade the canberra-gtk module but it is already the newest version. 

I'm using Matlab 2020a.

Comment: @tmlgr I have this exact same issue. Any luck on solving this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your /home/user/.bashrc and add this line:

alias matlab='export GTK_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0; export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965; /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/matlab'

save and open a new termianl window then execute

> matlab

See if it works. Your might have to change your matlab version in the last part which you can check using matlabroot in MATLAB terminal.

For more, check here:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/342906-could-not-initialize-shared-resources-for-x11graphicsdevice#answer_270207